# How to add HTML code dynamically from Java file in Wicket?

Tags: java, html, dynamic, wicket, addition

I am working on How to add HTML code dynamically from Java file in Wicket. I have multiple
links on my web page but don't want to design separate page for every link. I just want to
add my exiting HTML code dynamically from Java file.

For this purpose I used following code.

```
public class DynamicHtml extends Panel{

public DynamicHtml(String id) 
{
    super(id);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    String dynamicHtml = createDynamicHtml("divIdName");
    Label divLabel = new Label("divLabel",dynamicHtml );
    divLabel.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
    add(divLabel);
}

private String createDynamicHtml(String div_id) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    StringBuilder divSB = new StringBuilder(512);
    divSB.append("<div id=\"");
    divSB.append(div_id);
    divSB.append("\"></div>");

    return divSB.toString(); 
}

}
```

Html Code:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <span wicket:id="divLabel"></span>
</wicket:panel>
```

But I am not able to under stand how to pass exiting html code i.e "divIdName" in above code.
Please give me some advise or any guideline or references.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, which part isn't working as you'd like it to but generally you should use

```
<wicket:panel>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="divLabel" />
</wicket:panel>
```

So your code will generate valid XHTML.

Other than that, if you want to replace the markup dynamically, you should override the `getMarkup()` method of your Panel. See [JavaDoc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getMarkup%28%29)